# SQL query where if any job steps fail it need to be notified to user, when job is executed

Tags: t-sql, sql-job

Is there any SQL query where if any job steps fail it need to be notified to user, along with job execution for only failure notifications.

For example:

If we have Test job and it has 6 steps, if 4th step failed and rest all succeeded in this case it needs to notify user with job name and step name and failure for the particular step reason.

Thanks

I have tried few t-sql queries which have limitations that are, to send on daily basis or sending all the failure job's steps at a time. But my requirement is when job is executing if particular step of that job is failed immediately it need to notify the user.

Comment: Agent has a built in feature for this, called Notifications. Why not use that? Otherwise you would, ironically, need to have an agent task to run this SQL regularly and find those failed runs.

Comment: Hey Thom,  Notifications are being used to send only for job success, failure and completion if i am not wrong. I believe there is no built feasibility to send notifications when job step fails (particular step of the job)

Comment: So are you not failing the Job after the Step fails?

Comment: I've never had the need to do anything like this so not sure if it will work but you could add additional steps that fire the email, then in the advanced properties of each step, use the "On Success/Failure" Actions to direct it to the correct step.

Comment: No Thom, Scenario here is we will be having multiple steps in the job right, If any step failed so the job will be partially succeeded. For which ever steps failed, for those steps we need to notify user as failure of job step immediately with job execution.